# dereferencing void pointers with casting

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I was experimenting with void pointers and I came across following problem. When I compiled the following code it was all right but when I ran it on my machine it wouldn't give me results instead the prompt The program has stopped working appeared(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mLcnk8kTFUeEtmYnlOaWJ6T3c/view?usp=sharing) , I can't figure out what is happening behind the scenes,is there any issue regarding dereferencing `void` pointer.

Further it'll work if I use the commented code instead of original one.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     void* ptr;
     int dupe = 5;
     *(int* )ptr = dupe;  // ptr = &dupe;
      printf("The value at ptr is %3d",*(int* )ptr);
 }
```

I'am using gcc on CodeBlocks.

Comment: At the line 6 you dereference a pointer which points nowhere (it holds junk address) and you try to put the value of `dupe` there (i.e. to nowhere).

Comment: Note that `*(int* )ptr = dupe;` is NOT `ptr = &dupe;`. The second assignment is absolutely valid and does not cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that upon some compilation,the junk address assigned to it is valid ?

Comment: "the junk address assigned to it" -- It's not assigned, it's whatever junk is on the stack. That almost certainly is 0, which is a protected page so you're getting an access violation.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, `ptr = &dupe;` is like writing your friend's address on a postcard, and `*(int *)ptr = dupe;` is like scribbling on the postcard and then going to your friend's house and telling him to meet you at the location you wrote on this postcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to dereference a pointer without allocating memory to it. Which causes `segmentation fault` or `undefined behaviour`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void* ptr;
    int dupe = 5;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(dupe)); /* alloc memory for ptr */
    *(int* )ptr = dupe;
    printf("The value at ptr is %3d",*(int* )ptr);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;

}
```

If you don't plan to allocate memory then just replace `*(int* )ptr = dupe;` with `ptr = &dupe` in your code, as now `ptr` will point to a valid memory location of variable `dupe`. 
Refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for more details on undefined behaviour

Comment: `(int *)ptr` causes UB by using uninitialized pointer value, even if it is not dereferenced after

Comment: So,why does it works out in the when I use the commented code at line 6 instead of original ,without using malloc() ?

Comment: @BigO the other code is different. Different code does different things

Comment: @BigO `ptr = &dupe` is not even remotely like `*(int* )ptr = dupe`.

Comment: I understand that they both doesn't resemble at all,but the comment is not written to relate them,I just wanted to know what this statement is doing to make the program work correctly.

Comment: @BigO Well, it's obvious if you understand *anything* about pointers, so you clearly need to study up. And it's bizarre and totally confusing and misleading to comment something with something that doesn't relate to it. The commented out code should be on the previous line.

Answer (score 3):

```
6.       *(int* )ptr = dupe;  // ptr = &dupe;
```

The pointer ptr does not point to a valid memory location. What you have written in the comment, is what you should have done.

The statement `ptr = &dupe` will make the ptr point to the memory location of the variable `dupe`.

Comment: Found your answer useful, but alas! repo problem to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. void* ptr; --->ptr is a void pointer that means it can hold an address of any data type, but currently it is not pointing to any address.
2. *(int* )ptr = dupe ---> ptr point to no where and you are trying to put a value which is not valid.
3. ptr = &dupe; --> in this case ptr will point to address of dump which is a valid one.
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer `int *ptr`, usually a address value, is like the number of a box. Here `int` is the box type, it hints that this box is designed for putting a `int`. Of course, you can also cast it **carefully** to accommodate other kind of stuff, like `(otherKindType*)ptr`.
When try to deference a pointer with `*ptr = someValue`, like to get the object inside the box, you should promise that it points to some accurate place.

Code1(Can work):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void* ptr; // ptr is a pointer, it should point to somewhere 
    int dupe = 5; // a box (named dupe) fitted for int which hold 5
    ptr = &dupe; // ptr points to that box named dupe
    printf("The value at ptr is %3d",*(int* )ptr); // get content inside the box
}
```

Code2(Not work):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void* ptr;// pointer, point to a random place
    int dupe = 5;
    *(int* )ptr = dupe; // To put 5 to the box that pointed by ptr
                        // But now, ptr still points to a random place
                        // oops! To write to a random box is dangerous!
                        // It will cause error like `BUS error`
                        // Sometimes, to read a random box can output wired value.
    printf("The value at ptr is %3d",*(int* )ptr);
}
```

Code3(Can work):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void* ptr;
    int dupe = 5; 

    int new_box;//added         
    ptr = &new_box;//added, now ptr points to new_box        

    *(int* )ptr = dupe; // To put 5(content of dupe) to the box that pointed by ptr
                        // That is to put 5 to new_box
    printf("The value at ptr is %3d",*(int* )ptr); // get content inside the box
}
```